# How to Speed up mysql results

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a user passing a string value, we will say the word `'make'` and am having an issue:

First I have to get the `keyword_id` of the search string for instance `'make'` has `keyword_id = 1234`. Then I need to look for any records in **15 different tables** that have that `keyword_id` and compare the `link_id` of each to yet another table and return all records from THAT table for each `link_id` in the previous result.

I have two statements that work, but they are very slow to return results. Is there a better way to get `site_id` and `url` from links if the other two conditions are found to be true?

This is my query:

```
SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword0 AS k0 ON k0.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k0.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%' 

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword1 AS k1 ON k1.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k1.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%' 

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword2 AS k2 ON k2.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k2.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%' 

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword3 AS k3 ON k3.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k3.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword4 AS k4 ON k4.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k4.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword5 AS k5 ON k5.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k5.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword6 AS k6 ON k6.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k6.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword7 AS k7 ON k7.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k7.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword8 AS k8 ON k8.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k8.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword9 AS k9 ON k9.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = k9.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyworda AS ka ON ka.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = ka.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keywordb AS kb ON kb.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = kb.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keywordc AS kc ON kc.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = kc.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keywordd AS kd ON kd.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = kd.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyworde AS ke ON ke.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = ke.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'

UNION ALL

SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keywordf AS kf ON kf.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = kf.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'
```

BUT very slow - any ideas or help would be much appreciated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM search1_keywords AS k
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword0 AS k0 ON k0.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword1 AS k1 ON k1.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword2 AS k2 ON k2.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword3 AS k3 ON k3.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword4 AS k4 ON k4.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword5 AS k5 ON k5.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword6 AS k6 ON k6.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword7 AS k7 ON k7.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword8 AS k8 ON k8.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyword9 AS k9 ON k9.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyworda AS ka ON ka.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keywordb AS kb ON kb.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keywordc AS kc ON kc.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keywordd AS kd ON kd.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keyworde AS ke ON ke.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_link_keywordf AS kf ON kf.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
INNER JOIN search1_links AS l 
ON l.link_id = k0.link_id OR
l.link_id = k1.link_id OR
l.link_id = k2.link_id OR
l.link_id = k3.link_id
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'
```

ANY Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe don't have 15 different tables?

Comment: I agree with Strawberry, why do you have 15 tables..

Comment: What you have is a database design that's not suited to your use case. I'd strongly recommend reworking it into one that follows [database normalization best practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If a simple search query is several pages long, that should serve as a **red flag** that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the insane database schema where you have 15 different keyword tables...

Perhaps, in a subquery, you could perform your union of the keyword tables. Then join to that union once. Joins are expensive, and your current method has you performing multiple joins for every keyword table.

```
SELECT l.link_id, l.url, l.site_id, l.visible, k.keyword_id, k.keyword 
FROM 
     search1_keywords k
     INNER JOIN (
           SELECT keyword_id, link_id FROM search1_link_keyword0
           UNION ALL
           SELECT keyword_id, link_id FROM search1_link_keyword1
           UNION ALL
           ... and on and on
     ) AS keyword ON
           keyword.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
     INNER JOIN search1_links AS l ON l.link_id = keyword.link_id 
WHERE k.keyword LIKE '%make%'
```

Comment: This looks like it might do it - i will have to try it and let you know later in the week when i can test the result time - the 15 tables are storing relationships of ALL possible keywords found when indexing a site and files and the links that included them for other purposes and to make those queries faster and eliminating the tables is not possible I did think about creating one big one in addition but 1+ million records or more ouch...might be slower THANKS MUCH JNevil

Comment: I can guarantee you that storing them all in one table will be faster for READ. That is unless there are circumstances where you only need to read a single table at a time. At that point though, you should consider using partitioning (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html)

Comment: Yes in some cases only one particular table is being used from the search1_keywords{char1-15} especially during the indexing process and the creation of many other tables THANKS MUCH JNevil  this does exactly what i was hoping! and thanks to everyone else for the other considerations too!